# Managing Android App Development Between Computers

Tags: android, svn

A friend and I are developing an application on android but we live in 2 different cities. What are some good applications that helps manage the entire project (Like the all the files)? We tried using dropbox but ran into some problems. Is SVN a viable option?

Comment: Of course, SVN is viable. Either svn or git should work just fine for you. I personally use git on bitbucket.org, which is free for private projects. SVN should have some free options available for you as well. It's just that I haven't used SVN in a while. It seems the big trend now is to use git, although you can't really go wrong with Subversion either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SVN or GIT. I think GIT would be better in your case. Dropbox is not atall a good solution. using GIT or SVN you guys can checkin files and pull the changes other has done. It would be very easy to manage project in this case.